# labels should start from 0 or 1 in caffe if use softmaxwithLoss as loss layer?

Tags: neural-network, computer-vision, deep-learning, caffe, image-segmentation

Two questions:

1.For  MultinomialLogisticLoss, the label should start from 1, but the caffe doc says it should start from 0.http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/doxygen/classcaffe_1_1SoftmaxWithLossLayer.html

2.The shape of score(bottom[0]) is N*C*H*W, and N*1*1*1 for label(bottom[[1](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/doxygen/classcaffe_1_1SoftmaxWithLossLayer.html)]) for MultinomialLogisticLoss.
In segmentation task, the label shape is the same as bottom[0], ,that is N*1*H*W, But caffe didn't report any error in my test.

The two problems confuse me though I hav read some docs and segmentation project codes.

Answer (score 0):

1. Labels should start from zero: caffe uses the label to index into the prediction array.
2. Using [`"SoftmaxWithLoss"`](http://caffe.help/manual/layers/softmaxwithloss.html) with `axis` parameter, you can tell caffe to treat the `axis` dimension as the probability vector and have multiple predictions (i.e., `Nx1xHxW`) per batch. In that case, the label shape should match `Nx1xHxW` and not `Nx1x1x1`.